# GitHub Tag Message Markdown

Tags: bash, github, github-api

How do I make a tag commit/push message show up as markdown on GitHub?

The closest I’ve seen is [someone suggesting](https://github.community/t/markdown-in-git-tag-message-not-rendered-in-release/1428) to make a custom script defining the “body”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@VonC, that is good where gh is available, however, I'm in an environment where it's not... as such, I created the following bash script using the api. (clearly all below `$vars` need to be either defined or substituted for working example)

`COMMIT_BODY` can be markdown (e.g. `COMMIT_BODY="**This is markdow**"`)

```sh
res=`curl --user "$USERNAME:$TOKEN" -X POST https://api.github.com/repos/${ORGANIZATION}/${REPO}/releases \
-d "
{
\"tag_name\": \"$VERSION\",
\"target_commitish\": \"$BRANCH\",
\"name\": \"$VERSION\",
\"body\": \"$COMMIT_BODY\",
\"draft\": false,
\"prerelease\": false
}"`
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try and use the [GitHub CLI gh](https://cli.github.com/) (after [installation](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation), and [login](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login)), and its [`gh release create`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_release_create) command in order to pass a markdown file as release notes.

```
gh release create v1.2.3 -F changelog.md
```

That would do it all: tag, message tag, release notes and publication of said release to GitHub.
Right from your local workstation/repository.